# Error while using woe procedure in klaR package

Tags: r

I have noticed that for some reason the procedure woe from the klaR package will produce an error while trying to execute it on a data.frame with one column being a one-level factor. Here is an example:

```
a<-factor(rep(c("BAD", "GOOD"), 5))
b<-factor(rep(c(1,2), 5))
c<-factor(rep(c(2,3), 5))
d<-factor(rep(1,10))
df<-data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

Now the execution of

```
woe(a~., data = df[,-4])
```

won't produce any errors, whereas

```
woe(a~., data = df)
```

will crash with the following:

```
Error in applywoes(object[[i]], x.fact[, which(names(x.fact) == names(object)[i])]) : 
  Factor Levels do not match!
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Seems for me that the problem is that `d` has only one level as a factor. Nonetheless, the definition of woe should give a value of 0 for such a factor...

Is that an error in the procedure implementation or (for some strange reason) a deliberate behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this is not a deliberate behaviour. From what I read on Git( https://github.com/cran/klaR/blob/master/R/woe.R ), fonctions such as "woe.default" usually start with a couple of check of common error cases. The error you get is obviously checked.
You should probably contact directly the team behind this package to get proper answer.